# inactiveConnectionTimeout vs maxIdleTime on oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, ucp, stale

Can anyone help me understand what is the difference between these two properties `inactiveConnectionTimeout` and `maxIdleTime` while using `Oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSource`

Oracle documentation doesn't giving clarity and giving impression both are same. I am unable to understand then why we have two properties?

Oracle Docs reference:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12826/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSource.html#setInactiveConnectionTimeout_int_

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12826/oracle/ucp/jdbc/PoolDataSource.html#setMaxIdleTime_int_

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between the two properties, you can use any one of them. May be the maxIdleTime property was added in PoolDataSource to make it consistent with other connection pools.